# Running a Spring Boot Application with fixed locale

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, localization

I am working on a server application without a user frontend. To ensure that all parts of the application will generate only English message I would like to ensure that the application will use only a specific locale.

After reading the docs and some googling I came to the conclusion that I have to do the following:

1. Setting the locale programmatically in the `main` method via `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH)`;
2. Provide a bean instance of `FixedLocaleResolver` as locale resolver for the application.

Is this correct or this there a better way to achive my goal?

Answer (score 9):

you can put

```
spring.mvc.locale=en_EN
spring.mvc.localeResolver=fixed
```

in your application.properties or application.yml(of course in yaml format).

Spring will automatically read those properties.

I am not aware of any other better way.

Comment: Can this also be done for session locale or only for fixed locale?

Answer (score 4):

Since SpringBoot 2.4.0 use:

```
spring.web.locale=en_EN
spring.mvc.localeResolver=fixed
```

Comment: with spring boot 2.5.3 i had to use `spring.web.locale-resolver=fixed`

Answer (score 3):

In `application.yml`:

```yaml
spring:
  web:
    locale: en_EN
    locale-resolver: fixed
```

Comment: This combination works well for me in Spring Boot 3.0 .
Thanks Ashley!