# Set Default Validation Error from English to Spanish - Spring BindingResult

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am having a problem, i have my project in English, it is OK for me, but when "BindingResult" return validation errors it is in English and i don't want to change every field in application.properties.
I need that messages in English by default instead make for everyone.

like this:

NotEmpty.marca.nombrem=El campo no puede estar vacio

Can you help me guys? please.

Comment: The error messages are only available in English by default. If you want them in Spanish, you will need to add translations for them yourself. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you're asking, do you mean you want to override the default validation messages? If that's the case, I believe `javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty.message=El campo no puede estar vacio` in the message source should work for you

Comment: @WimDeblauwe i was talking about default messages, when it null, empty, limit character... i found solution.
spring.mvc.locale=es_MX
spring.mvc.locale-resolver=fixed

Now i can see all default messages in spanish.

Comment: Ah, if you want a fixed locale that is the way to go indeed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50763180/running-a-spring-boot-application-with-fixed-locale